# Am I eligible to some compensation if Eva Air changed the destination of my flight (was Hakodate, and became Sapporo)?

Tags: usa, air-travel, japan, compensation

Am I eligible to some compensation if Eva Air changed the destination of my flight (was TPE -> HKD [Hakodate Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakodate_Airport) via flight [BR138](https://www.google.com/search?q=BR138), and became TPE-> Sapporo ([New Chitose Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Chitose_Airport) a.k.a. CTS) via flight [BR116](https://www.google.com/search?q=BR116), which is 3.5 hours away from Hakodate by train) 17 days before the flight?

The reason for the change of destination wasn't communicated to me, but weirdly I see on Google Flight I can still book flight BR138 for the same date. However, I might be ok to head to Sapporo if some compensation is given (e.g., free accommodation at Sapporo, or free train from  Sapporo to Hakodate). As a side note, the entire flight path is a round trip from the United States (in case this changes the compensation rules), specifically it used to be SFO->TPE->HKD->TPE->SFO and became SFO->TPE->CTS ; HKD->TPE->SFO.

Comment: Did the airline not explain to you how they intended to get you to Hakodate?

Comment: @MichaelHampton No explanation given in the email I received notifying me of the change of destination (and interestingly the text message I received in addition to the email didn't even mention the change of destination: it only contains the change of departure/arrival time and flight number). I was hoping to get more information regarding compensation rules before calling them.

Comment: Have you checked your booking on the “manage my booking” section of their site? I would expect such messages to be automated, but maybe they are sent manually and someone forgot to update the details between messages for two different flights or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to say from Eva's conditions of carriage (https://www.evaair.com/en-global/conditions-of-carriage/). Call the airline and ask.

> 9.2 CANCELLATION, CHANGES OF SCHEDULES, ETC.
>
> 9.2.1 When circumstances so require, EVA may without notice substitute alternate Carriers or aircraft, or cancel, terminate, divert, postpone
>   or delay any flight or the further right of carriage or reservation of
>   Passenger or aircraft deployment and determine if any departure or
>   landing should be made, without any liability except to refund in
>   accordance with the Conditions of Carriage. EVA’s regulation and/or
>   the applicable laws, the fare and Baggage charges for any unused
>   portion of the Ticket:
>
> 9.2.1.1 because of any event beyond our control (including, but without limitation, meteorological conditions, acts of God, Force
>   Majeure, strikes, riots, civil commotion, embargoes, wars,
>   hostilities, disturbances, or unsettled international conditions)
>   actual, threatened or reported; or
>
> 9.2.1.2 because of any fact or event not reasonably to be foreseen, anticipated or predicted; or
>
> 9.2.1.3 because of any government regulations, demand or requirement; or
>
> 9.2.1.4 because of shortage of labour, fuel or facilities, labour difficulties of us or others.
>
> 9.2.2 Except as otherwise provided by the applicable law, if EVA cancel a flight, fail to operate a flight reasonably according to the
>   schedule, fail to stop at destination or Stopover, or cause Passenger
>   to miss a connecting flight on which Passenger holds a confirmed
>   reservation, EVA shall, in its reasonable discretion option, either:
>
> 9.2.2.1 carry the Passenger at the earliest opportunity on another EVA’s scheduled Passenger services on which space is available; or
>
> 9.2.2.2 within a reasonable period of time reroute the Passenger to the destination indicated on the Ticket or applicable portion thereof
>   by EVA’s own scheduled services or the scheduled services of another
>   Carrier, or by means of surface transportation. If the sum of the
>   fare, excess Baggage charge and any applicable service charge for the
>   revised routing is higher than the refund value of the Ticket or
>   applicable portion thereof, EVA shall require no additional fare or
>   charge from the Passenger, and shall refund the difference if the fare
>   and charges for the revised routing are lower; or
>
> 9.2.2.3 make a refund in accordance with the provisions of Article 10.2. And shall be under no further liability to the Passenger.